# Breadth First Search Pseudo Code Understanding

Tags: algorithm, data-structures, artificial-intelligence, graph-theory, breadth-first-search

[image: BFS from my textbook]

I have two questions regarding the pseduo code above.

1. What does the function SOLUTION(node) do? How would one implement it?
2. On the 3rd last line, we check if the child is not in the frontier. How would one check for that in a FIFO queue?

Comment: In particular: (1) There are plenty of explanations on line for BFS; this is essentially Dijkstra's algorithm.  Asking SO to write code for you is beyond the site's purpose.  (3) Asking SO to proofread your implementation is *far* beyond the stated purpose.  Run the code.  Test it.  Debug it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. `SOLUTION(node)` returns the full solution to the problem instead of just a node. In a pathfinding problem, it might return a full path from the start to end node

Example:

```
def SOLUTION(node): 
    result = []
    while(node.predecessor is not None):
        result.append(node.predecessor)
        node = node.predecessor
```

2. Linear search the frontier. If this isn't possible, it will still work as long as you check whether the node is in explored after it is dequeued, but this requires extra memory.

Comment: And then return the reversed result?

Comment: How would one validate your second claim? Why would the check be unnecessary?

Comment: Yeah, you're right the result should be reversed. The check is unnecessary because instead of checking each node when it is _added_ to the frontier, we can check when it's _removed_ from the frontier, and all the nodes still get checked. This isn't quite equivalent to what I wrote above, so I've edited